# Does wireguard route all traffic to the VPN server or just specific IP addreses?

Tags: networking, vpn, wireguard

I has setup wireguard so I can access my NAS remotely on top of OpenMediaVault with the wireguard plugin

I was wondering does wireguard route all traffic to the VPN server or just specific IP addresses?

But more specifically, how do I route requests to my local servers which I think *need to include* the DNS server (in my case pi-hole in Docker in a swarm on the same server as the NAS) from the VPN client but only those requests and leave the rest on the regular Internet?

Answer (score 0):

Like most other VPN systems, Wireguard doesn't make any such decisions on its own – it will route exactly those prefixes that you've configured to be routed through the connection, which may be anywhere from "all traffic" (/0 route) to "a single IP address" (/32 route). So you do this by making a list of IP addresses/prefixes that you want to be routed and specifying it in the tunnel configuration.

The exact place where you configure that depends on which of several tools you'll be using to configure the connection, as Wireguard by itself is just a raw network tunnel (i.e. more like a VPN *framework*). For example, if you're using the 'wg-quick' tool on the client, will automatically set up routes based on the AllowedIPs= setting (or you could opt out of that and configure routes in some other way), whereas something like OpnSense would have its own interface.

(And unlike e.g. OpenVPN, there isn't even any mechanism in Wireguard to get the routing configuration from the server – for that matter, there *is* no designated "server" in Wireguard – so it's all down to what routes you configure on the client itself.)